# Multi-language, how Craft determines the CopyFrom after adding website and Section

Tags: localization, craft3, sections, language

The question is admin (backend only), not Twig :

Where to Manage "copy from" site when adding new website and add section to this website. The "Copyfrom" takes place in the background after activating the section.

When adding a new (multilanguage) website and setting the section to that language it copies data to this new website or language.
I did a test and exported the "content" table as csv to see what happens.

- When adding a new website, it copys the structure to that language  (more lines in csv)
- When activating a section on the new website it copies the content to that language (more lines in csv from that section)Looks logical so far....But "What" determens the "copyFrom" content ?Introducing a new language now copies always "German" content.I really want to choose that part (when adding the Sections).

This is the structure in websites:

website.at  websiteAt   de-AT    https://website.at/        website.eu
website.com websiteCom  en-US    http://website-comdev.nl/  website.eu
website.de  websiteDe   de-DE    https://website.de/        website.eu
website.eu  websiteEu   en     V https://website.eu/        website.eu
website.fr  websiteFr   fr       https://website.fr/        website.eu
website.nl  websiteNl   nl-NL    https://website.nl/        website.eu
website.sk  websiteSk   sk-SK    https://www.website.sk/    website.eu

Example:  If i add website.zz and activate the section, the content is filled with german content (? maybe the first in the list). I want to manage the copyFrom and now we don't know wich default content is taken by introducing a new website/language.